# Do I add source files to the folder containg Project.sln or Project.vcxproj?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, directory

I am new to C++ and unfamiliar with the process behind linking to directories. I am using Visual Studio 2010

I want to add a `.cc` file to a project I am working on and am curious how to go about it. If in my project I right click "Source Files" and add the file I want, do I need to link the Source Directory to the folder containg this `.cc` file?

What if I copied and pasted this `.cc` file to my project? Would I place it in the folder containg the .sln files or the .vcxproj files? Do I still need to add a Source Directory link to something that's already in the project folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio, the folder that has the `.sln` file is the root directory for the solution. A solution can contain different projects in it. A C++ project is going to have a directory that has a `.vcxproj` file in it.

By default, when you add a new file to project (source/include/...), VS will put it in the root directory of that project (same directory as the `.vcxproj` file), but when you add an existing file, you can point to where that file is and that doesn't have to be in the root directory. You can make directories inside the project directory to better organize your directory structure.

Just remember that the local `#include` directives are usually in relative path to where the source file is, so if you need to refer to those files you need to put the relative path into the `#include` directive. For example, if your source files are under a directory called `sources` and the headers under `headers`:

```
#include "../headers/myheader.h"
```

or

```
#include "..\\headers\\myheader.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

At last in my enviroment all source and headers files for the project reside in the directory with the `.vcxproj` file in it.  So in my case if I have a project named Test then that would be

```
My Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Test\Test
```